# how to get unique values set from a repeating values list

Tags: python, perl, parsing

I need to parse a large log file (flat file), which contains  two column of values (column-A , column-B).

Values in both columns are repeating. I need to find for each unique value in column-A , I need to find a set of column-B values.

Is this can be done using unix shell command or need to write any perl or python script? What are the ways this can be done?

### Example:

```
xxxA 2
xxxA 1
xxxB 2
XXXC 3
XXXA 3
xxxD 4
```

### output:

```
xxxA - 2,1,3
xxxB - 2
xxxC - 3
xxxD - 4
```

Comment: I tried to get unique values list of column-A , using the shell commands  - 'cut' , 'sort' , 'uniq'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Python dictionaries where the dictionary keys are column A values and the dictionary values are Python's built-in [Set type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) holding column B values

```
def parse_the_file():
    lower = str.lower
    split = str.split
    with open('f.txt') as f:
        d = {}
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
        for A,B in [split(l) for l in lines]:
            try:
                d[lower(A)].add(B)
            except KeyError:
                d[lower(A)] = set(B)

        for a in d:
            print "%s - %s" % (a,",".join(list(d[a])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_the_file()
```

The advantage of using a dictionary is that you'll have a single dictionary key per column A value. The advantage of using a set is that you'll have a unique set of column B values.

Efficiency notes:

- The use of try-catch is more efficient than using an if\else statement to check for initial cases.
- The evaluation and assignment of the str functions outside of the loop is more efficient than simply using them inside the loop.
- Depending on the proportion of new A values vs. reappearance of A values throughout the file, you may consider using `a = lower(A)` before the try catch statement
- I used a function, as accessing local variables is more efficient in Python than accessing global variables
- Some of these performance tips are from [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Testing the code above on your input example yields:

```
xxxd - 4
xxxa - 1,3,2
xxxb - 2
xxxc - 3
```

Comment: Use collections.defaultdict, change `d = {}` to `d = defaultdict(set)`, and then you can get rid of the wordy try-except, just do `d[lower(A)].add(B)` and the defaultdict will take care of init'ing new sets for first-time-seen keys.

Answer (score 5):

Perl 'one-liner' intended/expanded out so that everything fits in the window:

```
$ perl -F -lane '

      $hash{ $F[0] }{ $F[1] }++;
  } END {

      for my $columnA ( keys %hash ) {

          print $columnA, " - ", join( ",", keys %$hash{$columnA} ), "\n";
      }
  '
```

Explanation will follow if I see a concerted attempt on the part of the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple multimap:

```
class MultiMap(object):
    values = {}

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.values[index]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if not self.values.has_key(index):
            self.values[index] = []
        self.values[index].append(value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.values)
```

See it in action: http://codepad.org/xOOrlbnf

Comment: -1 : Learn the std lib, collections.defaultdict does the same as your MultiMap.  Also: has_key has long been deprecated in favor of `key in dict`, in your case `if not index in self.values:`; and the OP wanted sets, not lists.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (%v, @row);

foreach (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        $_ = lc($_);
        @row = split(/\s+/, $_);
        push( @{ $v{$row[0]} }, $row[1]);
} 

foreach (sort keys %v) {
        print "$_ - ", join( ", ", @{ $v{$_} } ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
xxxA 2
xxxA 1
xxxB 2
XXXC 3
XXXA 3
xxxD 4
```

Did not focus on variable names. From example i see they are not case sensitive.

Comment: ++ for noticing cases, although i think that's a typo from the original poster

Answer (score 0):

```
f = """xxxA 2
xxxA 1
xxxB 2
XXXC 3
XXXA 3
xxxD 4"""


d = {}

for line in f.split("\n"):
    key, val = line.lower().split()
    try:
        d[key].append(val)        
    except KeyError:
        d[key] = [val]


print d
```

Python

Comment: You can cut out the try/except by using `d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)`

Comment: in this python code , the colum-B values are repeating as below   {'xxxd': ['4'], 'xxxa': ['2', '1', '5', '2', '1'], 'xxxb': ['2', '1', '4', '2'], 'xxxc': ['3']} . actually It should be like {'xxxd': ['4'], 'xxxa': ['2', '1', '5',], 'xxxb': ['2', '1', '4'], 'xxxc': ['3']}

Comment: @Mariselvam not exactly sure what you mean. @nmichaels thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

```
while() {

($key, $value) = split / /, $_;

$hash{lc($key)} = 1;

push(@array, "$key$value");

}

foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {

@arr = (grep /$key/i, @array);

chomp(@arr);

$val = join (", ", @arr);

$val =~ s#$key##gi; 

print "$key\t$val\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl oneliner:

```
perl -lane'$F[0]=~s/.../lc$&/e;exists$s{$F[0]}and$s{$F[0]}.=",$F[1]"or push@v,$F[0]and$s{$F[0]}=$F[1]}{print"$_ $s{$_}"for@v'
```

You can remove `$F[0]=~s/.../lc$&/e;` if your key is case sensitive (which is not true in your test data) or use `$F[0]=lc$F[0];` or `$F[0]=uc$F[0];` if you can unify your key to lower or upper case.